# How to Unit Test checkboxes / radio buttons in a React Testing Library form?

Tags: reactjs, forms, testing

It's pretty much my first time writing unit tests in React and i think i'm understanding most of the code that's already written but i'm struggling a bit here and there, i must've missed something.
In fact i'm trying to write code in a test file that asserts if a checkbox is checked after using fireEvent.click() on it :

```
    const checkbox = screen.getByLabelText("Modalité 1");
    console.log(checkbox); // returns a HTMLInputElement with 'checked: false' which to me, 
                           // confirms that i get an element of the type checkbox.
    fireEvent.click(checkbox); // also tried with userEvent.click(checkbox);
    expect(checkbox).toBeChecked();
    console.log(checkbox); // returns exactly the same thing as before, with 'checked: false'.
```

The error message shows Expected: true
Received: false

I didn't find this exact error anywhere else, but instead found other solutions implying other test methods which only made things more complicated :

```
    fireEvent.change(checkbox, { target: { checked: true } });
```

Instead of making the user click on the checkbox, i believe this method changes the property 'checked' diretly and isn't realistic.

The non-test javascript file contains the following : (code uses @material-ui)

```
    <div key={modalite.value} className="modalite-container">
                    <FormControlLabel
                      className="modalite"
                      name={this.props.name}
                      value={modalite.value}
                      control={
                        <Checkbox
                          onChange={(event) =>
                            this.handleChange(event, modalite)
                          }
                          checked={
                            this.state.selected.indexOf(modalite.value) > -1
                              ? true
                              : false
                          }
                        />
                      }
                      color={styleStore.isTypeMIS ? "mis" : "primary"}
                      label={
                        <div className="precisez-container">
                          {label}
                          {modalite.precision ? (
                            <div>
                              <input
                                label="précisez"
                                variant="outlined"
                                type="text"
                                className="precisez colored"
                                placeholder={t("entrez_precision")}
                                name="precision"
                                value={valuePrecision}
                                onChange={(event) =>
                                  this.handleChangePrecision(
                                    event,
                                    modalite
                                  )
                                }
                              />
                            </div>
                          ) : (
                            ""
                          )}
                        </div>
                      }
                    />
```

and i have no idea how to correctly test that. Is the click event wrong ? Is the check-testing method wrong ?

Any ideas ?